# Javascript array sort not working right when many equal elements

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array with a custom comparer function.

The comparer function only cares about the order between two specific elements.

In the example below you'd expect 'a' to appear before 'b' after sorting, but it's not.

```
var ar = ["b", "c", "d", "a"];

ar.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x == 'a' && y == 'b') { return -1; }
  if (x == 'b' && y == 'a') { return 1; }
  return 0; // only the order between 'a' and 'b' matters.
});

console.log(ar);

// ar is still ["b", "c", "d", "a"];
```

So why isn't 'a' before 'b'? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Think about your comparator being called on the successive pairs of your list:

```
"b", "c" --> 0
"c", "d" --> 0
"d", "a" --> 0
```

Your comparator says all the pairs are equal, so the order doesn't need to be changed at all.

Since you don't care what order the other elements appear in (is this right?) then make your comparator say "a" is less than anything, and "b" is greater than anything:

```
ar.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x == 'a' || y == "b") { return -1; }
  if (x == 'b' || y == 'a') { return 1; }
  return 0; // only the order between 'a' and 'b' matters.
});
```

Comment: I did not care the order of other elements in the example. In the real scenario where this issue came up, there CAN be more than one pairings where the order matters.

Comment: I was trying to z-sort sprites. When they are intersecting, I could determine which should be on top. If the sprites were not intersecting, I was returning 0 from the comparer.

Answer (score 0):

If `'a' = 'c'`, and `'b' = 'c'` - which according to your function it is, then `'a'` also equals `'b'`.

Comment: Yeah that's what must be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the Array.prototype.sort function like this...

```
Array.prototype.sort = function( sortFunc ){
    if( typeof sortFunc !== "function" ){
        sortFunc = function(a,b){
            return a-b;
        }
    }
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i <= len; i++ ){
        sortFunc( arr[i], arr[i+1] );
    }
    return arr;
}
```

As you can see `Array.prototype.sort` only supplies the `sortFunc` functions with elements that are only one unit apart.

So sortFunc( "b", "a" ) won't happen because their indexes are not 1 unit apart.